# simple text slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been searching for a simple text slider, using jquery or simple css3 one. I will add the model of one Im looking for and explain the functionality. The contents should be displayed and slide option should be like the one in the snap. the other div below has contents related to the so when the above one slides, the contents in the below div should also change and the bottom div should only be visible if the user opens it on clicking main div. is there any useful plug in for this mode?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Coda Slider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/) plugin for jQuery.The customization of making the content div open when the user clicks on a button or any other ui element will have to be manually included. It shouldn't be hard. You can use the jQuery functions of [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to do the required.

Comment: the number of slides needs to be calculated realtime.. its not fixed

Comment: @user1371896 I am not sure i understand. Coda Slider is html based. So you can add html content and then call codaSlider().

Comment: Thats fine, bt can we speed up the way slides move?? its too slow..

Comment: It is given in the documentation. Use slideEaseDuration. Default: 2000
  Description: Sets the speed one panel moves to the next. You can use it like $(div).codaSlider({slideEaseDuration: 500})

Comment: If you are using this as your solution, can you tick it as the right answer?